# Spring Boot. Get page of child entity from page of parent entity

Tags: mysql, spring-boot, hibernate, spring-data-jpa

I'm using Spring boot with mysql database.
I'm wondering how to paginate the child entities from a parent entities.

Here is the use case :

Parent has an unidirectional oneToMany relation with Child entity.
Here is a code sample :

```
@Entity
public class Parent{

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    @Column(name = "id")
    private Long id;

    @Column(name = "dateTime", nullable = false)
    private LocalDateTime dateTime;

    @OneToMany(targetEntity = Child.class, cascade = 
    CascadeType.ALL,fetch = FetchType.LAZY, orphanRemoval = true)
    @JoinColumn(name = "parent_id")
    private Set<Child> childs;
    ......
}

@Entity
public class Child {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    @Column(name = "id")
    private Long id;
    ......
}

public interface ParentRepository extends JpaRepository<Parent, Long>{}
public interface ChildRepository extends JpaRepository<Child, Long>{}
```

I need to get all child entity where parent dateTime is between X and Y but to get page of childs.

Any idea how to do this ?

I get page of parent where dateTime is between X and Y.From this page of parents for all parent I get list of childs so the page information from parents is not the same with childs.

One solution is to get all parents and from parents to get all childs and to return all childs but I need this to be pageable.

Thanks for all your time.

Comment: What is a "unidirectional oneToMany" (without `joinColumName`, without `referencedColumnName`) good for ?? To generate randomness & confusion?? To the core question: it would be a 1-liner, if you mapped it "doubly"... but maybe someone has a solution!?

Comment: @OneToMany(targetEntity = Child.class, cascade = 
    CascadeType.ALL,fetch = FetchType.LAZY, orphanRemoval = true)
    @JoinColumn(name = "parent_id")

Comment: sorry, is till don't get it! (the advantage of having (such perversion as) a "unidirectional OneToMany") ..and in your scenario it is not only "no advantage" but also a "blocker" (for me) (an unidirectional OneToMany is a reverse(/pervert) ManyToOne...and i just don't get [the hype](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=unidirectional+Onetomany))

Comment: solution to make bidirectional OneToMany/ManyToOne is solution but this change production database and is last solution.

Comment: (no structural change, but you are probably right regarding "constraints&indices" ..still worth a try(/test)!)..then you should go with "native query".

Comment: One solution is to get all id from parents where dateTime is between X and Y.With this list of ids to get all childs using ChildRepository and pageable.

Answer (score 0):

SELECT * FROM child c where c.parent_id in (SELECT id FROM parent where dateTime  between '2020-09-12 19:12:12' and '2020-09-12 20:12:12');

Answer (score 0):

If you want at most N children, you can just inverse the query. Something like the following in JPQL/HQL:

```
SELECT c, p FROM Child c, Parent p WHERE p.dateTime BETWEEN :start AND :end AND c MEMBER OF p.childs
```

The query is not very efficient though because it will create a subquery. So if you can change the model, add the inverse `@ManyToOne` association to child and use this query:

```
SELECT c FROM Child c JOIN FETCH c.parent p WHERE p.dateTime BETWEEN :start AND :end
```